# Why do the recommended import statements for Docusaurus fail?

Tags: docusaurus

Importing react components into a Docusaurus markdown file has a common pattern like:

- `import Figure from '@site/src/components/figure'` [github source](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/discussions/4633#discussioncomment-2616552)
- `import BrowserWindow from '@site/src/components/BrowserWindow'` [official docs](https://docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features/react#importing-components)

However, this pattern throws an error [in my application](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-5c7qs5-wquhko?file=docs/theirlabel/latest.md) when I include the following line in `docs/theirlabel/latest.md`:

```
import Figure from '@site/src/components/figure'
```

Throwing the following error

> ERROR in ./docs/theirlabel/latest.md 1:991-1039
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@site/src/components/figure'
> in '/home/projects/github-5c7qs5-wquhko/docs/theirlabel'

Commenting that line allows the site to [compile correctly](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-5c7qs5-heqiqg?file=docs/theirlabel/latest.md).

I've tried many variations of referencing/including the `figure.jsx` component without success, like:

```
import Figure from '/src/components/figure'
import Figure from './src/components/figure'
import Figure from '../src/components/figure'
import Figure from 'src/components/figure'
import Figure from './figure'
import Figure from '/figure'
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I tried changing your import to use import Figure from '../components/figures' and it appeared to work, i think this is a fork of your code sandbox that shows t https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-5c7qs5-u13hp6?file=docs%2Ftheirlabel%2Flatest.md,docs%2Fscious-search%2Flatest.md

Comment: That was the exactly the solution! So thankful for your help. If you want to post as answer, I'd be happy to accept it :)